# Reading a variable value inside a named function in javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mocha.js, backbone-views

This may be very simple but i lost my way in finding the answer,

I have a named function inside a Backbone view. I'm trying to write unit test for this named function and i could see a variable is being declared in function scope. The state of this variable changes based on certain scenarios.

I have instantiated the view object inside my test suite and when i do a console.log(viewObject.namedFunction) i see the entire function being logged properly. Now how do i access the variable inside the namedFunction, i was expecting something like viewObject.namedFunction.variableName but it will not work and when i did that, it was not working as expected.

If the variable is tied to viewObject scope then it would have been easy to access it. But in this scenario it is not so can some one please help me in getting a hold on the variable inside named function in view object from test suite.

Comment: perhaps it will be easier if you provide some sample code.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you're asking for is prevented because the scope within the function is inaccessible from outside of it. That is intended behavior. Unless your variable is declared outside of the function, or the function returns the variable, you will have no way to access it. Sample code would help clarify, but I think what you're asking for is not possible. If you could post sample code and what you hope to achieve, perhaps we can reach an alternate solution.

Comment: Here is a sample code,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a9d3mjwh/4/ (Please note this fiddle URL does not have any libraries/plugins added) this is just to see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your confusion, because when you define a variable using `var` in the `window` scope, it becomes a property on the `window` object...  It would seem to follow that when you define a variable in a child scope, it should become a member of the local context, right?  Nope.  Globals are special ;-)

In fact, if that *were* the case, there would be **no privacy**!

If you want `sign` to be public, be explicit.

```
obj = {
    namedFunction : function myself() {
        console.log(myself);
        myself.sign = 23;
    }
};
obj.namedFunction.sign;
```

The only problem with this approach is that you can now assign a new value to `sign` from anywhere.  The classic and preferred approach to this problem is to create a getter function for your private variable.

```
var obj = {
    namedFunction : function myself() {
        var sign = 3;
        myself.getSign = function(){return sign;};
    }
};
obj.namedFunction.getSign();
```

This isn't by any means the only approach, but I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Hey, thank you this approach works. But i feel for a testable javascript code it is always good to avoid local variables because it seems to be very difficult to handle it in test suites.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is like such:

```
namedFunction = (function(){
     var theActualFunction = function(){
          //Do something
          //Access variable like: theActualFunction.MyVariable
     };
     theActualFunction.MyVariable = "value";
     return theActualFunction;
}());
```

Comment: If you don't want to create a closure, you can also set the property from within the function itself.  Named function expressions can refer to themselves.